# How to rewrite the inequality to let them become convex

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

There is an inequality

$$\sum^{K}_{j=1} \mathbf h_k^H \mathbf F_j \mathbf h_k+\sigma^2_{a_{k}} \ge \frac{P}{1-\rho_k}.$$

The variable is $\mathbf F_j$, a $4 \times 4$ matrix, and $\rho_k$ is a value which is larger equal than $0$ but less equal than $1$ , that is, $0 \le \rho_k \le 1$.

If $P $ is a positive value,then equations on both sides of inequality is convex,but if $P$ is negative,the right hand side,$\frac{P}{1-\rho_k}$, will become concave.

How do I rewrite the formula to let left side is concave and the right side is convex,that is,

concave $\ge$ convex ,
when the $P$ is negative ?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without looking at the full optimization problem.

Comment: @LinAlg no offense !why?

Comment: If $P$ is negative your constraint does not in general describe a convex set. Perhaps it can be formulated when taking the full problem into consideration. What do you know about $F_j$ for example? BTW what exactly are constants and what are optimization variables?

Comment: @shineele perhaps a substitution of variables can help you, which affects the problem as a whole

Comment: i have edit the problem,it should be concave $\ge$ convex,the variable are $\mathbf F$ and $\rho$,the objected function is minimize the $\sum tr(\mathbf F_j)$

Comment: so no other constraints?

Comment: The only way I can see this working, per LinAlg's suggestion, is to create a new variable $\nu_k = 1/(1-\rho_k)$. So then the right-hand side becomes $P\nu_k$, which is affine (and therefore convex) for any $P$. But the question is whether or not you can rewrite the rest of your problem in terms of $\nu_k$ instead of $\rho_k$ and preserve convexity.